# Why does the creation of flink checkpoints differs so much

Tags: apache-flink

Can I somehow get more details what is going on while creating flink checkpoints? The time of creating a flink checkpoint differs by factor 10. That is at least what my jobmanager logfile tells me:

```
2017-02-14 09:03:43,234 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.checkpoint.CheckpointCoordinator     - Triggering checkpoint 161 @ 1487059423232
2017-02-14 09:08:17,447 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.checkpoint.CheckpointCoordinator     - Completed checkpoint 161 (in 271425 ms).
2017-02-14 09:08:43,233 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.checkpoint.CheckpointCoordinator     - Triggering checkpoint 162 @ 1487059723233
2017-02-14 09:09:46,684 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.checkpoint.CheckpointCoordinator     - Completed checkpoint 162 (in 61951 ms).
```

Checkpoint 161 take only a minute to be created while the following checkpoint 162 take 4,5 minutes (it goes on with 8 minutes and than get back to 1,5 minutes).

- Could that be related to some TumblingWindows I am using (with a window duration of 3 minutes)?
- Is there any way to influence the checkpoint creation beside the frequency (and location)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Apache Flink 1.2 offers very detailed checkpointing statistics in the web UI.

Check out the pull request that introduced the feature for some screenshots: https://github.com/apache/flink/pull/3042

The UI will help you to understand where the time is being added.

These documentation pagees are probably worth reading:

- [Monitoring Checkpointing](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.3/monitoring/checkpoint_monitoring.html)
- [Debugging and Tuning Checkpoints and Large State](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.3/monitoring/large_state_tuning.html)

Comment: Thanks @rmetzger - thanks for the info. The link "Debugging and Tuning Checkpoints and Large State" gave me the right hint.

Comment: @TobiSH Can you share how you solved this problem? I am facing the same issue.